# Creating a error box that makes the program wait for an input

Tags: vb.net

If my program has a text box empty in the search field it will still run all the way through and complete its process. I want an error box to pop up stating an value must be put in and pause the program until a value is put in.

This is what i started with i just don't know how to pause the program.

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    Form4.Show()
End If
```

I have my form 4 show options, solutions, etc. . .

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Modal dialogs "pause the program", but WInforms also has Validation events for this sort of thing. Explicit form instance would be another valuable thing to learn/use. (Visual Studio is not to blame for this).

Comment: Instead of using `Form4.Show`, use `Form4.showDialog` That should solve your problem. When you click on `OK` on form4, you should still be able to access the properties of your input controls on that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    Form4.ShowDialog()
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Please do not only dump code, but try to explain as well why this solves the problem. Read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Michel, I do try to explain when necessary but the .ShowDialog was addressed in comments and Exit Sub is about as self-explanatory as possible.

Comment: Mary's answer was perfect and the explanation was explained in the comments above. Thank You!